# Unfortunately application has stopped+ google map+can not determine Access_Fine_Location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm just trying to follow this tutorial (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android). I've added required permissions to AndroidManifest as well. But when I run the app of emulator it gets stopped. in my logcat it says that permission to Access_fine_location is missing; but that is already added in manifest. Can anybody help me to find the problem please?

Logcat

```
09-13 12:31:31.768    7900-7900/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2, PID: 7900
    java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzg$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzc$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:132)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzh(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zznt(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.onConnected(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzoD(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzoF(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-13 12:31:31.873    7900-7911/? I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4802(565KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(192KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 5MB/5MB, paused 2.786ms total 344.385ms
09-13 12:31:31.924    1307-1906/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2/.MapsActivity
09-13 12:31:31.936      955-955/? D/gralloc﹕ Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
09-13 12:31:31.936      955-955/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
09-13 12:31:31.936      955-955/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1121825449
09-13 12:31:31.936      955-955/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
09-13 12:31:32.161    1892-1892/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 193 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 12:31:32.452    1307-1321/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{f2b5723 u0 com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2/.MapsActivity t17 f}
09-13 12:31:32.684    1307-1326/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 12:31:32.852    1307-1326/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 12:31:32.903    1307-1326/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 12:31:42.833    1307-1321/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{f2b5723 u0 com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2/.MapsActivity t17 f}
09-13 12:34:40.558    1307-1317/? I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.904ms for cause Background
09-13 12:36:26.282    1307-1318/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 6356:android.process.media/u0a5 (adj 15): empty for 1806s
09-13 12:36:31.964    7900-7900/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 7900 SIG: 9
09-13 12:36:31.968    1307-1417/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.scibdisrat.myapplication2 (pid 7900) has died
09-13 12:36:31.991    1307-1463/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 7900 uid 10057
09-13 12:36:32.040    1892-1892/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 12:36:32.090    1307-1320/? W/ProcessCpuTracker﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 7960
09-13 12:36:32.238    1307-1326/? W/AppOps﹕ Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
09-13 12:39:32.768    1307-1323/? E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-13 12:39:32.796    1307-1323/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader﹕ Failed to read cpu-freq
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
            at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8003)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1364)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
            at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8003)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1364)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
09-13 12:39:32.796    1307-1323/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader﹕ Failed to read uid_cputime
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
            at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8032)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1364)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
            at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8032)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1364)
            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
09-13 12:40:36.429    1307-1307/? I/EntropyMixer﹕ Writing entropy...
09-13 12:41:00.127    1307-1321/? I/ProcessStatsService﹕ Prepared write state in 81ms
```

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.*******.myapplication2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SDK 23 onwards, you need to request permissions at runtime. You can read about runtime permissions here:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Put simply, before you write the logic to access location services, you need to check if the app has the needed permission. In this case ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is a Dangerous permission. So the user has to explicitly grant permission. It is a good practice to explain to the user why the permission is required. After the user responds to the request, find out whether the permission was granted and then proceed accordingly. Either continue with the code which needs the user's location or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved my issue. Since ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION has some issues with sdk version 23, I selected a lower targeted SDK.